# How can i split $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}*(\frac{4}{7})^{n+k}$ into 2 sums?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Hi i would like to split
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}*(\frac{4}{7})^{n+k}$

into two summations.
Is this even possible ?

Comment: How about $2(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}*(\frac{4}{7})^{n+k}) - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}*(\frac{4}{7})^{n+k}$?

Comment: I dont really think that this would help me out with finding the value of the summation or whether it converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\left(\dfrac47\right)^{n+k}$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac47\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\left(\dfrac47\right)^k$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac47\right)^n\left(1+\dfrac47\right)^n\text{ using }(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk x^k$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac{4\cdot11}{7^2}\right)^n$$

$$=\dfrac1{1-\dfrac{4\cdot11}{7^2}}$$ as  $\left|\dfrac{4\cdot11}{7^2}\right|<1$